# Is "Media image of the politician Name Surname in BBC Radio" a correct use of articles in the title of my work?

Tags: articles

I need to find a correct use of articles in English translation of the title of my work, written in my native language.

The politician in question is simply a well known MP, not a president or PM. Which one is correct?

(1) Media image of a politician Name Surname in BBC Radio

(2) Media image of the politician Name Surname in BBC Radio

Is the last one correct?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use either "a politician" or "the politician" depending on context (is it someone you were previously discussing, or just a politician you happened to have an image of?), but neither sentence sounds very natural. I'm not sure what you mean by "in BBC Radio" - do you mean an image of the politician in the radio studio? "at BBC Radio" might be clearer. It would be better to say "photo/photograph" if it's a photo, although I guess it could be a cartoon/caricature.

Comment: Media image as of how the media viewed the politician while BBC Radio is the source or information. I know it doesn’t sound very natural, I’m aiming for a direct translation from my native language

Comment: I now wonder if a missing indefinite article before "Media image" may confuse readers that the work will be about a photo or picture rather than a series of recorded audio commentaries in BBC Radio, making an overall media image of the politician

Comment: If it's a title, you can generally drop all articles: *Media Image of Politician Joe Blow **on** BBC Radio.*

Comment: _BBC Radio's image of politician GivenName FamilyName_ would be shorter. As @gotube suggests articles often get dropped in titles and headlines. Yesterday a free paper in the UK had _Baroness Bra in PPE Bust-up_ on its front page (it is about a supposed financial scandal).

Comment: @gotube It’s a title for my bachelor thesis, I hope it will stand. Thank you for your suggestion, it sounds so well without any articles. I’ll use on as a prepostion.

Comment: @mdewey it sounds good but I’d like to stay closer to the original title. Thank you for your suggestion and confirming I can omit articles in titles. In case of sticking with an article, what would you choose?

Comment: @slunko Good luck with your thesis!

Comment: If I had to choose between _the_ and _a_ I would choose _the_.

Comment: I have no idea at all what you mean. "English translation of the title of my work". Why not actually give us the title, instead of putzing around.

Comment: @Lambie The original title is not in English, how that would be relevant?

Comment: @mdewey thank you

Comment: "I’m aiming for a direct translation from my native language." Yes, that seems to be the problem.  "direct translation" is very often wrong. Also, media image and radio is anbiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this does not go unanswered this brings together fragments from the comments.

gotube suggested that the correct preposition was *on the radio* not *in the radio*

Both gotube and I felt that titles could dispense with articles but now that it has been clarified that this is the title of an academic thesis more formality might be appropriate so the title would read

> Media image of the politician Name Surname on BBC Radio

It is a specific politician so *the* is best, using *a* politician with their name is rather contradictory.

Comment: The OP said: Title of my work. How can "the politician Name Surname" refer to a "title of my work"??